# Property performance

Tags: c#, properties

I need to know if there are some performance problem/consideration if I do something like this:

```
public Hastable Properties=...
public double ItemNumber
{
  get { return (double)Properties["ItemNumber"]; }
  set
{
  ItemNumber = value;
  Properties["ItemNumber"] = value;
}
}

Public string Property2....

Public ... Property 3....
```

Instead of accessing the property directly:

```
public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
public string prop2 { get; set; }
public string 3...{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Did you profile it? Is it the bottleneck of your application?

Comment: @irsog, the question you mentioned is completely different... I suggest you read it again.

Comment: It shoudln't be the bottleneck in your application if it's not used in some intense 10 million cycle calculation. Use Dictionary<string,double> to spare yourself the cast. Bothe the pieces of code you suggested DO NOT do the same thing. First one can hold many values, second one - just one

Comment: There *might* be a site related problem with the `set` part...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your performance requirements... Accessing a `Hashtable` and casting the result is obviously slower than just accessing a field (auto-properties create a field implicitly), but depending on what you're trying to do, it might or might not make a significant difference. Complexity is `O(1)` in both cases, but accessing a hashtable obviously takes more cycles...

Answer (score 0):

Well, compared to the direct property access it will surely be slower because much more code needs to be executed for the get and set operations. But since you are using a Hashtable the access should be pretty fast. You are also getting an additional overhead because of the casting since you are using weakly typed collection. Things like boxing and unboxing come with a cost. The question is whether all this will affect noticeably the performance of your application. It would really depend on your requirements. I would recommend you performing some load tests to see if this could be a bottleneck.

Comment: i've made a quick load test it's 5 times faster. But how i can i decide if it is too or is acceptable?

Comment: That will depend on your project requirements in terms of speed and response time. Different projects have different requirements. It is something that should be defined in the design phase when writing the specifications for the product you are developing.